# Questions on implementing Google OpenID on a certain Google Apps domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-apps, google-openid

I'm trying to implement a Google OpenID login

I have the following questions:

1. Where can I get the value of the variable openidurl in the line

IAuthenticationRequest request = openid.CreateRequest(openidurl);

2.. How can I restrict the login for a certain Google Apps Domain only?

The code is the following:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
        var response = openid.GetResponse();
        if (response != null)
        {
            switch (response.Status)
            {
                case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:

                    var fetch = response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();
                    string email = string.Empty;
                    if (fetch != null)
                    {
                        email = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
                    }

                    //FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(response.ClaimedIdentifier, false);
                    Session["email"] = email;
                    Response.Redirect("profile.aspx");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OpenLogin_Click(object src, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string openidurl = "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=initial_id"; //auxiliary initial id. ??????
        //The Request
        using (OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty())
        {
            IAuthenticationRequest request = openid.CreateRequest(openidurl);

            var fetch = new FetchRequest();
            fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
            request.AddExtension(fetch);

            // Send your visitor to their Provider for authentication.
            request.RedirectToProvider();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, this is the first time I use Google OpenIDs.

Comment: Checkout this link https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID
or this StackOverFlow Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042601/how-to-use-openid-in-asp-net

Comment: I have already checked them out when I wrote the code above (which eventually works) and I am using DotNetOpenAuth. Thanks for the reply though...